# favicon not displaying in IE in Production

Tags: favicon

The favicon is shown perfectly in all version of IE in UAT. But once the application pushed to Production, the favicon is not showing in all the version of IE. The source file used is the same. Below are some of the methods I've tried but the favicon still not showing.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Assets/img/favicon.ico?v=2" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Assets/img/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="../Assets/img/favicon.ico?v=2" />
<link rel="icon" href="../Assets/img/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

(after putting the favicon.ico to root folder)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="www.websiteurl.com/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="icon" href="www.websiteurl.com/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

The favicon.ico is a valid icon file and it's not just converted from .png file.

What did I missed out here?

Comment: Did you try with a leading slash like `/favicon.ico?v=2` instead of `favicon.ico?v=2`? Did you try to actually access your icon with `http://www.websiteurl.com/favicon.ico?v=2` to make sure it's available?

Comment: Yes I have tried /favicon.ico?v=2 and the icon is displayed correctly in http://www.websiteurl.com/favicon.ico?v=2. Weird part is the favicon displayed in UAT without a problem but not showing in Production.